# Listing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I stop this Javascript code from passing the last number of the iteration to the delete function?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="lista"></div>
</body>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        var dados = ['vassoura','lixo','papel'];
        function deletar(elemento){
            console.log(elemento);
        }
        function listar(){
            var div = document.getElementById('lista');
            for(i in dados){
                campo = document.createElement("output");
                button = document.createElement("button");
                button.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                    deletar(dados[i]);
                });
                button.innerHTML="deletar";
                div.appendChild(campo);
                div.appendChild(button);
                console.log(i);
                campo.value = dados[i]+" ";
                console.log(dados[i]);
            }
        }
        listar();
    </script>
```

it is passing the last number corresponding to iteration because when I click on the button the iteration has already been made and finished

Comment: The question is really a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Ops... sorry guys...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like here is a common mistake with a variable scope.

Simplest way is to either use closure or replace `for(i in dados)` at least with `for(let i in dados)`

Answer (score 0):

First ,get the length of dados. and check when i = dados_length (last element) then skip that code which you want to skip.